# sparse checkout gives me an error stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD

Tags: git, jenkins

When I try to do a GIT sparse checkout in Jenkins, I get the following error:

```
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision b1697de347cafa3afbd9efc364b2874994e88b0e (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git config core.sparsecheckout true # timeout=10
 > git read-tree -mu HEAD # timeout=10
Command "git read-tree -mu HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD
```

I'm using the Multiple SCM plugin that Jenkins provides.

The files get copied to the directory, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

The node is running on Centos 7

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I am experiencing the same problem and the proposed solution below (deleting jenkins workspace) does not work for me.

Comment: Follow-up for the comment above. Myy problem, while related, was that the workspace path to jenkins was wrong. Fixing this path solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting jenkins job workspace fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

This (actually non-fatal) error went away for me when I updated the branch from `master` to `*/master`.